# Site deployed with Meteor deploy in 0.9 is throwing errors

Tags: meteor

I just upgraded my meteor app to version 0.9, and everything works great on localhost. But when I deploy to the meteor server, it deploys fine, but when i am trying to access the website its not loading, and throws the following errors on console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined 

Uncaught ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
```

And the website is showing up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `meteor update` and check out the logs server side when you run your app. it's very likely you're using a package that is not compatible with meteor 0.9

Most likely this may be `mrt:bootstrap-3`, though it can be another.

To fix bootstrap, if bootstrap is the proble, you can do this:

```
meteor remove mrt:bootstrap-3
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: Thanks it was indeed mrt:bootstrap-3. Even though I had installed mizzao:bootstrap, the mrt:bootstrap-3 package was throwing a warning, in the logs, and I had ignored that. Removing the package and deploying worked.